# having problems with sizing css grid container

Tags: html, css, frontend

I'm a newbie at using grid so please, if the question is to stupid, don't judge me  so hard lol
Anyway I'm trying to have a layout of 5 divs.  so I have the basic outline but I'm trying to make this grid take up 100% of the screen width and I'm very much failing at that.

Here is my html:

```
<div class="parent">
<div class="div1"> </div>
<div class="div2"> </div>
<div class="div3"> </div>
<div class="div4"> </div>
<div class="div5"> </div>
</div>
```

And here's css:

```
.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 5vw);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(6, 5vw);
  grid-column-gap: 60px;
  grid-row-gap: 60px;
  width: 100%;
}

.div1 { 
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 4 / 4; 
  background-color: green;
}

.div2 { 
  grid-area: 4 / 1 / 7 / 4; 
  background-color: black;
}

.div3 { 
  grid-area: 1 / 4 / 3 / 7; 
  background-color: black;
  float: right;
}

.div4 { 
  grid-area: 3 / 4 / 5 / 7; 
  background-color: black;
  float: right;
}

.div5 { 
  grid-area: 5 / 4 / 7 / 7; 
  background-color: black;
  float: right;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated
Thanks for your time <3

Comment: Why is each column given a width of 5vw if you want to fill the width? Perhaps have a go with 1fr?

Comment: @AHaworth I tried it yesterday and it didn't work, then I saw your comment tried again and it did work lol

Answer (score 0):

You only change grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 5vw); to grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);

```css
.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(6, 5vw);
  grid-column-gap: 60px;
  grid-row-gap: 60px;
  width: 100%;
}

.div1 {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 4 / 4;
  background-color: green;
}

.div2 {
  grid-area: 4 / 1 / 7 / 4;
  background-color: black;
}

.div3 {
  grid-area: 1 / 4 / 3 / 7;
  background-color: black;
}

.div4 {
  grid-area: 3 / 4 / 5 / 7;
  background-color: black;
}

.div5 {
  grid-area: 5 / 4 / 7 / 7;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
      <div class="div1"></div>
      <div class="div2"></div>
      <div class="div3"></div>
      <div class="div4"></div>
      <div class="div5"></div>
    </div>
```